# How to escape a single quote inside a double quote string in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql

I am trying to run the follow bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

DB_USER='abc'
DB_USER_PASSWORD='123'
DB_MAGENTO='db_magento'

sudo apt-get update  
echo debconf mysql-server/root_password password $DB_USER_PASSWORD | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf mysql-server/root_password_again password $DB_USER_PASSWORD | sudo debconf-set-selections        
sudo apt-get -qq install mysql-server > /dev/null # Install MySQL quietly
sudo mysql -uroot -p123  -e "CREATE SCHEMA ${DB_MAGENTO} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;SHOW DATABASES;CREATE USER \'${DB_USER}\'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${DB_USER_PASSWORD};GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO \'${DB_USER}\'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;SELECT Host,User,Password FROM mysql.user;"
```

The error I am getting is `ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\''.`
Seems to be related with `\'${DB_USER}\'` .

How to escape these single quotes properly?

### UPDATE

Afetr @Sergiy suggestion I am getting another error:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

DB_USER='ila'
DB_USER_PASSWORD='123'
DB_MAGENTO='db_magento'

    mysql -uroot -p123  -e "SHOW DATABASES;CREATE USER '${DB_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ${DB_USER_PASSWORD};GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '${DB_USER}'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;SELECT Host,User,Password FROM mysql.user;"
```

Error:

```
$ sudo ./installMagento.sh 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| db_magento         |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to use `\` with double quotes:

```
$ DB_USER='abc'; echo "test '${DB_USER}'"
test 'abc'
```

Alternatively, you can break the double quote, and escape the single quote - that's where it's necessary:

```
$ DB_USER='abc';  echo "test"\'"${DB_USER}"\'
test'abc'
```

Yet another way would be to use `printf` with command substitution and using hex value for the quote (`\x27`):

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p123  -e "$(printf 'CREATE SCHEMA \x27%s\x27 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;SHOW DATABASES;CREATE USER \x27%s\x27@\x27localhost\x27 IDENTIFIED BY %s ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO \x27%s\x27@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;SELECT Host,User,Password FROM mysql.user;' ${DB_MAGENTO} ${DB_USER} ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}  ${DB_USER})"
```

---

Side note: you have 3 commands in the script calling `sudo`. This is redundant. Just run the whole script as `sudo myscript.sh` and remove the need to add `sudo` to each of those lines.

Comment: hey @Sergiy, thanks for you suggestion. I've tried your first suggestion but I still getting an issue. I dont understand what could be. I put an update.

Comment: Ok I have found the issue. Should have a single quote in password also.

Comment: What if it's a mysql command with ` like in mariadb syntax example SELECT  `id`